# Word 2010 advanced (orange) Content Control field that updates automatically

Tags: microsoft-word

Having the developer tab open and activate Design Mode I try to create a Content Control field that updates all instances of itsel

Example:

[image]

As you can see then it does not update all instances of test123. I know that it need to be orange in order to have this property, but how do I make it like that????

I know that it is possible because I had a wierd document that I saved once and that created some of these magic orange content fields

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is control controls that are linked to Custom XML. The orange controls are linked to document properties and work on the same basis .

If you want a quick solution you can actually just use one of the document property based content controls to achieve what you are looking for. Change the name of the content control by going to the Developer Tab, enabling Design Mode and changing the name under properties. The content is stored in the document property and you will see the linked behavior still remains intact when you modify one of the controls.

Otherwise you will need to setup your own custom XML property. This is not so easy, however one of the Microsoft MVP created a [great program](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html) to help with that.

Comment: I tried this with the 'Status' content control which I gave the title 'Version' because there is no 'Version' property out-of-the-box. It works, except with no text inserted it displays '[Status]'.