# Long fields in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, automation, field-codes

I'm aware of both *fields* and *quick parts* features in Word. I'm searching for something, that combines these two features: I want to enter a block of long, formatted, perhaps multiline text, which may be later reused in several parts of the document. When I modify the definition though, I want all of the instances to be updated as well.

Is there a way to achieve such thing in Word 2010?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/509231/word-2010-advanced-orange-content-control-field-that-updates-automatically